# Sorting an array in a function in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86

Using the selection sort algorithm implement a function (in assembly) that sorts a given array of integers in ascending order. The inputs to the function are arraySize and arrayOfIntegers. The function will re-arrange the numbers in the in the array as it sorts. I's sure i am able to compute the index of the min value in the second value(i debugged to check). However, I can't the values the min and the current index to swap. I read similar questions yet I can't seem to get it - It's been 3 days and I can't get it. I'm very new to assembly language, and would appreciate the help. Please and Thank You 
My swapping begins at END_FOR_2:

```
void array_sort( int arrayOfIntegers[], int arraySize )
{
    int temp;

    __asm{
        push eax
        push ebx
        push ecx
        push edx
        push esi
        push edi

// BEGIN YOUR CODE HERE

// Note: You can safely use the 6 registers listed above as well
// as the variable temp in your code, if needed.
    mov esi, 0
    mov edi, 0
    mov ecx, 0
    mov eax, 0
    mov ebx, arrayOfIntegers
    mov edx, arraySize
    dec edx
FOR_1:
    cmp esi, edx
    jg END_FOR_1
    mov edi, esi
FOR_2:
        inc esi
        mov eax, esi
        dec esi
    WHILE_2:
        cmp eax, arraySize
        jge END_FOR_2
        IF_1:
            mov ecx, dword ptr [ebx + eax*4]
            cmp ecx, dword ptr [ebx + edi*4]
            jg END_IF_1
            mov edi, eax
        END_IF_1:
            inc eax
            jmp WHILE_2
END_FOR_2:
    mov eax, dword ptr[ebx + 4*edi]
    mov ecx, dword ptr[ebx + 4*esi]
    IF_2:
        cmp edi, esi
        je END_IF_2
            mov temp, ecx
            mov ecx, dword ptr[ebx + 4*edi]
            mov eax, temp
    END_IF_2:
        inc esi
        jmp FOR_1

END_FOR_1:

// END YOUR CODE HERE

   pop edi
   pop esi
   pop edx
   pop ecx
   pop ebx
   pop eax
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With no comments in the code, it's a lot of work for anyone to figure out what you're using each register for.

The actual bug looks like it's in `IF_2`.  You get the min value you just found into `eax`, and the value for the next position to be sorted (`[ebx + 4*esi]`) into `ecx`.  Then you have some silly code that writes to and then reads from `temp`, without ever writing to either position in the array.  This should work:

```asm
# IF_2:
# cmp edi, esi  # more efficient to just unconditionally do stuff
# je END_IF_2
mov eax, dword ptr[ebx + 4*edi]  # or this value is already in ebp from the search loop
mov ecx, dword ptr[ebx + 4*esi]
mov dword ptr[ebx + 4*edi], ecx  # exchange values
mov dword ptr[ebx + 4*esi], eax
# END_IF_2:
```

Some other obvious things:

- It's more efficient to zero a reg by `xor`ing it with itself, rather than a `mov` insn with immediate data.
- To get eax = esi+1, do a `mov eax, esi` and `inc eax`.  Or `lea eax, [1+esi]`.  Not `inc` / `mov` / `dec`.

Your `WHILE_2` scans for the smallest element in the rest of the array, I think.  It would be better to keep the current smallest value in a register, instead of using `dword ptr [ebx + edi*4]` as an input to `cmp` every time.  So your loop could be

```
    mov ebp, dword ptr [ebx + edi*4]  # ebp = current min
    WHILE_2:
    inc eax
    cmp eax, arraySize
    jge END_FOR_2
    mov ecx, [ebx + eax*4]
    cmp ebp, ecx
    jg WHILE_2  # go to next iteration
    # IF_1: if (arr[cur] < min) { minpos = cur; min=arr[cur]; }
        mov edi, eax  # new minpos
        mov ebp, ecx  # new minval
    END_IF_1:
    jmp WHILE_2
```

Note that `eax` is incremented in a different place than before, and I used `ebp`.  This allows restructuring to put one less instruction (the unconditional `jmp`) on the common path.

If you can't use `ebp` (like if you need to compile with frame pointers on), then spill a different value to memory, and reload it after the loop.  Or just write 64bit code, because it's 2015 and the only x86 CPUs that can't run in 64bit mode are over 10 years old.  (even Atom CPUs are 64bit-capable now).  But anyway, if you run out of registers, spill something used infrequently to memory, not a value you use every time through a tight loop.

Also, I might have written the loop to increment a pointer, instead of using an indexed addressing mode.  `minpos` can be a pointer instead of an offset.  Then you don't need to keep the base address around in `ebx`, as well as two indices.